Does "The Pillar" ante debuff cards that were played but not scored?
The Ante for "The Pillar" states:

Cards played previously this Ante are debuffed

Does the debuff apply to cards that were played but weren't included in scoring? For example, if I played a pair of Aces with 3 other irrelevant cards that weren't scored, would those 3 cards be debuffed as well?

The Pillar specifically cares about played cards. A card that was played but not scored will still be debuffed.
